# How to check TCP buffer size in Spring Websocket(Jetty)?

Tags: websocket, jetty, spring-websocket, jetty-9

[How will websocket works when websocket client is too slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706503/how-will-websocket-works-when-websocket-client-is-too-slow)

The above link is the problem I want to solve. My server will push a lot of data to client. So it is possible that client side consumes too slow.

I want to **detect slow client** in my springboot app by checking TCP buffer size. But I don't know how to check the size in Spring Websocket (Jetty 9.2.x). I can't find any interface related to TCP buffer in jetty websocket source code.

If I can't, is there any other way to detect slow client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you can't access the TCP buffer.

Jetty websocket is beholden to Java's networking.

What you want to know is the WebSocket write results in TCP congestion / backpressure.

To do this, you pay attention to the write calls.

With blocking WebSocket it just a simple matter of doing the write, it won't return until the write has completed.  If it blocks then the write is likely TCP congested and you should back off from writing anything else.

With async WebSocket writes, you pay attention to the results of the write (either from the Future or the Callback) and don't write the next message until you have confirmed the current message has written successfully.

Failure to pay attention to the async write callbacks/futures results in message queuing (the queue has no upper limit and will grow to fit all available memory).

It's up to you, as a application using websocket, to decide what to do when you detect this slow write scenario.

Do you close the connection?
Do you drop some messages?
Do you queue messages at all?

If you do queue messages, do you have message priority or importance?
If a certain number of priority messages haven't been sent, do you then close the connection?
Do you hold onto those priority messages to resend when (if?) the client reconnects?
Do you have an expiration / timeout on the queued messages?
Removing messages that haven't been sent by X amount of time?

Comment: I don't use jetty to build my own server. I use spring-websocket which implemented by jetty-webosocket. And I read some source code of jetty-websocket. Does the queue in FrameFlusher work as "message queueing" ? https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/1a165aadec5ce98678e1e45a467c3fb5719ae52c/jetty-websocket/websocket-common/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/common/io/FrameFlusher.java#L45

Comment: I use async ws write. Maybe I can listen to the size of this queue to detect the TCP backpressure ? If not, perhaps the only way is to handle the future/callback.

Comment: You don't have access to the queue, that's just an internal implementation (subject to change).   Use the async future/callbacks, and handle them, don't ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Joakim Erdfelt.

But I found the slow client won't trigger the callback if the client is Chrome.
Server side throws error "Connection reset by peers".
I think the socket might be closed by Chrome when client's websocket buffer is full.

My final solution is in application level.

User should commit the message offset at some interval and server side compares committed offset at client side with the latest message offset at server side. Detect the slow client by the gap between these two offsets.